# How to query session.gc_maxlifetime?

Tags: php, session, session-state

I know how to set the duration of a session (both in a PHP file and in my `php.ini` file), but my question is the opposite of this. How can I see what is the current `session.gc_maxlife` value?

I work with a variety of shared hosting environments, all of which have different values. Most are the default 24 minutes, but some have variation.

I want to be able to pop up a warning to my users just prior to session expiration, but I also want my script to figure out that time delay based on the actual server settings.

I know that I can manually look up this info with `phpinfo();`, but am not aware of a way to get just this single value.

Is there a command for this that my googlefu is failing me on? Has someone written a function to calculate it?

Comment: I should also comment that it is not an option to simply config the value consistently on all the servers...as some hosting providers block this...frustrating...but i have to work with what i am given.

Comment: have you tried `ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in comments, thanks to yoda. I had to use:

```
ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime")
```